# How to manage amazon s3 bucket size?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image-processing, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using Amazon S3 for saving my uploads in my rails application.
But the bucket size is growing very rapidly, I have used [kraken image optimizeer](https://kraken.io/) for compressing images.But i want to know what else i can do for managing bucket size.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what your use case is, if you always need access to the files etc. Optimizing / resizing uploads is probably a good idea, however you can also have a look at [S3 lifecycle management](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html). With this feature you can for example delete old files or move them to AWS Glacier. See the [reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/manage-lifecycle-using-console.html) for an example on how to set this up using the AWS console.